# Set Macro In Excel With Visual Basic

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel

Im programming with Visual Basic 2010 Express. I export my visual basic data to Excel worksheet and i can design it. But is it possible to set a macro to excel worksheet from visual basic?

Comment: What you mean by "set macro to Excel"? Do you want to write macro whithin Excel file?

Comment: Yes, i would like to write macro to my excel worksheet from my visual basic project. (In my visual basic program there is a button when user clicks it, it opens an excel worksheet and set my data to excel)

Comment: Read: [Display the Developer tab in the toolbar](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/developer_tab2013.php) and watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 4 - Buttons, Toolbars and Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=KZgOwmS3iFY&index=4&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: Thanks but, im not working with excel. Im programming a visual basic project. Im opening excel from my visual basic program

Comment: Not sure about VB Express, but once you have a workbook reference you should be able to access the `VBProject.VBComponents` collection and be able to `Add` a `CodeModule`.

Comment: if it's always the same macro you want to add, save it as a text file and then import it into vbproject - less work than writing it in line by line